# solving system of linear equations in matrix form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I write equations like A +2B+C=30.  I got final answer to be 34 but textbook says answer is 39. I have double checked.  Is textbook wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What specifically did you get that $A$ equals?  What specifically did you get that $B$ equals?  etc...

Comment: Yes I think it is wrong...

Comment: The system is inconsistent...

Answer (score 0):

From the third column you get $B+D=16$ so from the second one $A=7$; from the third row you get $D=7$ so from the fourth column $C=10$. Now you can calculate the last row: $C+A+D+C=34$. But if you check the first row with these numbers you'll get 35!! as JMoravitz pointed out to me, so the system is impossible.

Comment: $D=7$ and $B+D=16$ would then imply that $B=9$ but from these numbers this implies $A+2B+C=7+18+10=35$, not $30$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes you are right...so the system seems impossible